# LINQ with JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, SUM, multiply values two List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I need convert this statement SQL to LINQ:

```
SELECT SUM(L.total_linea) AS Total, I.porcentaje
FROM linea_pedidos L
INNER JOIN iva I ON L.id_iva = I.id_iva
GROUP BY L.id_iva
ORDER BY I.porcentaje DESC
```

At the moment I have done this, but I can not move forward.

```
from l in linea_pedidos
join i in iva on l.id_iva equals i.id_iva
select new
{
    l.id_iva,
    i.porcentaje,
    total = l.total_linea * i.porcentaje / 100
} into s
group s by s.id_iva into g
select g.Sum(t => t.total)
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in this? Why can't you move forward? What is wrong with what you've done?

Comment: I need show two columns and not only sum, How can I get two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include porcentaje in your grouping.

If you think about it, your sql query is the same as

```
SELECT SUM(L.total_linea * I.porcentaje / 100) AS Total, I.porcentaje
FROM linea_pedidos L
INNER JOIN iva I ON L.id_iva = I.id_iva
GROUP BY L.id_iva , I.porcentaje
ORDER BY I.porcentaje DESC
```

which you could translate to

```
from l in linea_pedidos
join i in iva on l.id_iva equals i.id_iva
select new
{
    l.id_iva,
    i.porcentaje,
    total = l.total_linea * i.porcentaje / 100
} into s
group s by new { s.id_iva , s.porcentaje } into g
orderby g.Key.porcentaje descending
select new { Total = g.Sum(t => t.total) , g.Key.porcentaje  }
```